# How can I Delete row tables in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete empty rows in MySQL,but is not working.
Maybe some of you can help me out.

Here is how it looks now [Table](http://i57.tinypic.com/2pu0q5v.jpg).

And this is the code , I am not sure if I wrote it correctly.

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM tasklist WHERE 'Task','Date','Description' IS NULL ");

mysqli_close($con);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple errors:

Each condition in your WHERE clause must have its own statement. Also, you need to use ticks, not single quotes around your column identifiers:

```
mysqli_query($con,"DELETE FROM tasklist  
                          WHERE `Task` IS NULL 
                          AND `Date` IS NULL 
                          AND `Description` IS NULL ");
```

Comment: There might be somthing wrong with my code , its not deleting.Thx tho ill see why its not working .

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is not correct it should be something as

```
delete from tasklist 
where Task is NULL
AND Date is NULL
AND Description is NULL
```